# Swagger - customize example request body

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger

I have a swaggerized Spring MVC endpoint for a POST operation. The operation takes a path param and a (json) request entity. When the swagger UI is generated, it automatically creates an example value of the request body data type. This example is based on a java entity in the application. The entity is used for some other operations, however for the POST operation, I do not want some of the entity fields exposed in the example. Is it possible to modify this example without modifying the existing java model? For example, is it possible to exclude in the below example `lastUpdate`.

[image]

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27779319/1754020

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to ignore `lastUpdate` in the example value using jackson annotations `JsonIgnore`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;    

public class Phone {
  private String phoneNumber;
  private String lastUpdate;
  private int status;

  public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
  }
  public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public String getLastUpdate() {
    return lastUpdate;
  }
  public void setLastUpdate() {
    this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
  }

  public int getStatus() {
    return lastUpdate;
  }
  public void setStatus() {
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding `@JsonIgnore` would also remove it from responses in other operations - which is not what I'm trying to achieve. I just want to hide it from the swagger.

Comment: Response and Request should be separate classes in your architecture if you don't want their settings cohesion.

Comment: Doesn't work when annotated either on field or on getter - disappears from the Model as well. This way it works the same as Swagger's "hidden" property.