# springboot+ swagger shows all parameters of associated objects also

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, swagger

I am using springboot 1.5.4, springfox-swagger2-2.7.0 for for developing a springboot application and swagger for rest api documentation. Swagger documentation and rest api response both are showing all properties of associated objects also I don't want to display the fields.

My entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long accountId;
    private String accountUid;
    private String accountName;
    private String contactPerson;
    private String emailId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_type_id")
    private AccountType accountType;

    // ...setter and getters
}


@Entity
public class AccountType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long accountTypeId;

    private String typeName;

    private String description;

    private int status;
    // setter and getters
}
```

Model class in swagger documentaion is:

```
{
  "accountId": 0,
  "accountName": "string",
  "accountUid":"string",
  "accountType": {
    "accountTypeId": 0,
    "description": "string",
    "status": 0,
    "typeName": "string"
  },
  "contactPerson": "string",
  "emailId": "string"
}
```

response for get account is:

```
{
  "accountId": 1,
  "accountName": "xxxxx",
  "contactPerson": "xxxx",
  "emailId": "test.abc@abc.com",  
  "accountType": {
    "accountTypeId": 1,
    "typeName": "xxxxx",
    "description": "xxxxx",
    "status": 1
  }
}
```

But in both response and swagger also I don't want to display all properties of account type except id.
The output I want is

```
{
  "accountId": 1,
  "accountName": "xxxxx",
  "contactPerson": "xxxx",
  "emailId": "test.abc@abc.com",  
  "accountType": {
    "accountTypeId": 1
  }
}
```

I am not able to find whether the problem is with swagger or spring data JPA.

Comment: You need to implement a marshaller , which controls what properties of a entity will go to the response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude Models or properties from swagger response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777537/exclude-models-or-properties-from-swagger-response)